# Is there a guaranteed order of evaluation to lapply (and friends?)

Tags: r

I've been happily using `lapply` (and variants `apply`, `sapply` and `vapply`) as a replacement for `for` loops. Most of the time the order of operation is not important, but I realize that I have also been using it in cases where the order of operations *does* matter. So far I haven't run into any problems, but I can't actually find a definitive answer (on SO or elsewhere) on whether or not `lapply` is guaranteed to evaluate the list sequentially. I remember reading a while back that `lapply` is basically just a wrapper for a `for` loop, but then there are posts like [this one](https://nicercode.github.io/guides/repeating-things/) that suggest the evaluation order is not guaranteed.

So, my question: Is there any documentation that **definitively states** whether or not the `*apply` family evaluates calls in the order they are given? Let's stick with single-process use cases.

**EDIT**

Well, I guess I answered my own question with this trivial example. Consider the following sequence of statements to be evaluated:

```
exprs = list(
  "a = 5",
  "b = a + 5",
  "c = b + 5",
  "d = c + 5"
)


# DOES NOT WORK
lapply(exprs, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))

# WORKS
for(x in exprs)
  eval(parse(text = x))
```

<s>So apparently I've been getting lucky this whole time.</s>

**EDIT 2** Ok, using `eval` in the example was a bad idea. The use case that got me worried was:

```
exprs = list(
  "a = 5",
  "b = a + 5",
  "c = b + 5",
  "d = c + 5"
)
library(PythonInR)
lapply(exprs, pyExec)
```

Which is evaluated sequentially.

Comment: @RichScriven, see my edit.

Comment: This is just a bad idea all together.  Objects should not be created from strings.

Comment: Close voters: this question is NOT asking for a recommended anything.

Comment: Also, the example in the blog post is silly. The for loop looks ugly, but it's really no more and no less complex than an equivalent lapply that uses an anonymous function. And in fact, in a situation like that where all you want is the side-effect (creating a plot), then a for loop is _better_ than an lapply (which will return an object that is immediately discarded).

Comment: `lapply(exprs, function(x) eval(parse(text = x), .GlobalEnv))` does, tho. You're trying to operate a warp drive w/o reading the manual. `*apply`, `purrr::map*`, etc operate sequentially. Period.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr---using `eval` for the example was a mistake. I did check the manual for `lapply` but it doesn't state that `*apply` operates sequentially, period---hence the SO post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example doesn't fail for the reason you think it does. It fails because each of your assignments takes place within the environment of the function evaluated by `lapply`. One such environment is created for each expression, and they're all independent; so earlier assignments can't be used by later ones.

If you had done instead:

```
exprs = list(
  quote(a <- 5),
  quote(b <- a + 5),
  quote(c <- b + 5),
  quote(d <- c + 5)
)

lapply(exprs, function(x) eval(x, .GlobalEnv))
#[[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 10

#[[3]]
#[1] 15

#[[4]]
#[1] 20
```

If you're looking for a definitive standard-quoting reply, I don't think it exists. R isn't a rigorously defined language like C, C++, Java or C#. However, since there's basically only one implementation, if your code works there, it'll probably work everywhere.

That said, you shouldn't rely on this behaviour. One of the advantages of `lapply` is that it's easily parallelisable to multiple processes/threads, by switching to functions like `parLapply`. The semantics that enables this assumes each iteration is independent of the others, so if you try to do what you're doing here, you lose this advantage.

From a readability/least-surprise point of view, a loop where later iterations depend on earlier ones is best expressed with a `for` loop. That's what you should use if your code needs it.

Comment: You can write "standard" C++ that won't compile to the same byte code (or even compile at all) everywhere.

Comment: "R isn't a rigorously defined language like C, C++, Java or C#."

Comment: You're wrong about C++. You pontificate quite a bit like that.

Comment: You seem a bit upset. I have no idea why. In any case, the point is that R doesn't have a formal standard, unlike many other well-known languages; so the best answer possible to this question is by looking at the (one) implementation's behaviour.

Comment: And of course, C++ _does_ have a standard, as I'm sure you're aware. Whether compiler vendors follow it to the letter or implement every feature is another issue, as is the variety of platforms C++ is available on.

Comment: Aha! Thanks @HongOoi, I had the feeling that using `eval` in the example would add some nuance.